# Is it correct to say "Next to the bed are three chairs"?

Tags: inversion, existentials

Is it correct to say "Next to the bed are three chairs" or is it rather "Next to the bed there are three chairs"?

Comment: Why do you think only one is correct?

Answer (score 6):

Both of your examples are correct, but they involve different grammatical processes, all three of them related to something called **information packaging** – presenting the same basic information in different ways.

Let's take a look at your sentences one at a time, using the grammatical framework and terminology outlined in chapter 16 of *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, co-authored by Ward & Birner.

---

#### Next to the bed are three chairs.

The first example involves a process called **subject–dependent inversion**.  The subject has switched places with a dependent of the verb:

> 1a. *Three chairs* are **next to the bed**.　→
>   1b. **Next to the bed** are *three chairs*.

As is often the case, the verb here is copular *be*, and the dependent is a locative PP (preposition phrase) complement.  The basic meaning of both sentences is the same, but the word order is different.

In this case, the inversion works fine.  Inversion isn't always appropriate, though.  In English, we tend to prefer to put old information at the beginning of a sentence, and new information toward the end of the sentence.  If we break that rule when we invert a sentence, putting newer information at the front of the sentence, it tends to sound strange.

---

### Next to the bed there are three chairs.

Your second example differs in two ways.  First, the basic sentence uses an existential construction with *there*:

> 2a. *Three chairs* **are** next to the bed.　→
>   2b. **There are** *three chairs* next to the bed.

We've inserted the dummy *there* in subject position, and the old subject *three chairs* in 2a has become a post-verbal complement in 2b.  Although *there* is now in subject position, the post-verbal complement *three chairs* is still understood semantically as the subject of the clause, so the basic meaning of 2a and 2b is the same.

There are some cases where an existential or a non-existential construction would be preferred, but in this case both sentences are fine.  This too is an information packaging construction, used to present the same basic information in different ways.  Because of our broad preference for old information at the beginning of a sentence, we tend to use existential constructions to move new information out of subject position.  In this case, even though 2a and 2b are both grammatical and make sense, 2b might be a little bit more common or natural for this reason.

Your second example has another difference.  Rather than subject–dependent inversion, we have a **preposed locative complement**:

> 3a. There are three chairs **next to the bed**.　→
>   3b. **Next to the bed** there are three chairs.

This construction differs in several ways.  First, the preposed constituent must be a complement, whereas with subject–dependent inversion it is usually a complement, but may be another type of dependent.  Second, rather than switching places with the subject, the preposed constituent simply moves to the front of the clause.  The subject stays in its basic position before the verb.

Once again this is an information packaging construction, so whether it's appropriate depends on factors like whether the information you're moving to the front of the sentence is old or new.  Factors like this depend on the context in which the sentence appears.  Once again, this sentence is fine – it presents the same basic information in a slightly different way.

---

### Which sentence should you use?

All of the example sentences I've discussed here are grammatical and have the same basic meaning, and all of them are okay.  They might be slightly more appropriate in one context or another.

For example, you might say *Next to the bed are three chairs* in a **narrative**, after you've already introduced and described the bed to the reader or listener.  The sentences with *there* are very natural and is more likely to appear in actual speech, for example if you're describing a room to your friend over the phone.

But really, there are no major differences between your examples, and we can't say that either of them is the correct choice.  They're both fine.

Answer (score 0):

They are both correct, although the second instance is much more likely to be "There are three chairs next to the bed".

Comment: Only as long as there is not a detailed description of the chairs (which admittedly is a different sentence), such as "Next to the bed there are three chairs; a big one, a little one, and one that's just right."

Answer (score 0):

You can see "There are three chairs next to the bed." Or Three chairs are next to the bed". These patterns are frequently used. But the patterns with fronting are also correct. They just show that you would like to *emphasize the place*. Both your sentences are correct.